# Run a command with su -c and exit when done

Tags: bash, ant, sh, su

I'm trying to run a command using another user using the following:

```
sudo su - myuser -c "/my/command.sh -Dparam=lorem | sed '/^BUILD SUCCESSFUL$/ q'";
```

The sh files calls an ant script. I need this to end when the BUILD SUCCESSFUL appears on the file. However, if I run this within myuser, it works. If I run it through another user, and using su -c, it doesn't exit at the end, and I need to press CTRL+C.

How do I exit at the end?

/my/command.sh contains the following:

```
nohup something.sh > /opt/lastrun.log &
tail -n 0 -f /opt/lastrun.log
```

Comment: It should exit. Consider providing the contents of `/my/command.sh` or provide a script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: `tail -n 0 -f /opt/lastrun.log` should keep running unless `/opt/lastrun.log` is not readable by the user. So you saying "if I run this within myuser, it works" doesn't make sense since that means having the error is the right way to do it.

Comment: It shouldn't, because `sed '/^BUILD SUCCESSFUL$/ q'` should exit the tail. In fact, it does exit it when i'm myuser

Comment: Ok I missed that. It is possible that `tail -n 0 -f /opt/lastrun.log` is running but `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` is never encountered. Do you not see other error messages like the shell failing to open `/opt/lastrun.log` for writing?

Comment: The string is encountered. No error message. It just hangs there until i press CTRL+C

Comment: Perhaps your nohup command still runs in the background after that and one of the parent processes waits for it to exit. Try explicitly adding a kill command to kill the process after `tail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by turning the pipe sed into

```
{ sed '/^BUILD SUCCESSFUL$/ q'; pkill -PIPE -xg0 tail; }
```

Comment: Nice use of `-g`.